# Target Display Mode on a 2011 iMac with a Linux PC

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xrandr, macintosh

I recently built a desktop PC, which is running Linux. I have an old (Mid-2011) 27" iMac, which I would like to use as a monitor (it has a nice 1440p screen). I am currently testing the connection on my laptop. I have a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adaptor which I am using to connect the iMac and the laptop (I would also connect the desktop PC in this way). I believe the ports on the back of the iMac are Thunderbolt 2 and not Mini DisplayPort, but I was under the impression that Thunderbolt had a superset of DisplayPort's functionality. I am aware that one would normally use the iMac as a display through Target Display Mode, which is usually invoked with `Command+F2`. Pressing this key combination does not seem to enable Target Display Mode, neither does it cause the laptop (also running Linux) to detect the display (through HDMI) as connected, either with *xrandr* or *arandr*. I have used this same iMac in the past in Target Display Mode with a MacBook Pro, so I know that it is capable of such a feature. Additionally, I have dual booted the iMac with Ubuntu and tried [a fix to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43491594/1825470). However, this method of overwriting kernel values seemed specific to the exact iMac for which it was written (mid 2010), and I received errors when running the included scripts (errors that I do not have the knowledge to debug). Does anyone know of a good way for me to use my mid-2011 27" iMac as a display for my Linux PC? I would prefer to not use  a networked solution (as I only have a wireless connection), but I would do so as a last resort.